# Connection point on a 2007 Impala for vehicle inspection

Tags: inspection

I recently had my 2007 Impala at a dealer for a routine lube, oil change, tire rotation,  and a NYS Vehicle Inspection.  Shortly after that I found puddles of water on the front passengers floor.  I took the car back to the dealer who said I had to go to a collision shop.  Collision shop fixed the problem and said someone had disconnected the drain hoses from both front door joints so as to make the rain water seep into the car.  I was told that the drain hoses do not fall off by themselves, someone has to manually disconnect them.

I have to go back to the dealer where I the lube and oil change and am a bit leery about them as I feel they may have caused the leak.

I would like to know if the drain hoses must be removed in order to do the NYS vehicle inspection and their failure to be reattached might have been an oversight by the mechanic who worked on the car.

Comment: I cannot imagine anything like that happening for an inspection. Here in VA, the only thing they take off the car is two wheels/tires to check the condition of the brakes. Since I don't know what crazy things might happen in NY, I'll leave this to someone who lives/works there.

Answer (score 2):

No, in NYS you don't have to remove the sunroof drain tubes and they have nothing to do with an inspection. And there aren't any drain tubes in the doors themselves.

IIRC the sunroof drain tubes run through the A pillars and into the front fenders. So it would be almost impossible to do on accident and very unlikely to have been done intentionally. If I had to guess the passenger drain was clogged and when the body shop removed the a pillars to check the hoses that they inadvertently detached the hoses.